# How to set up Ruby on OS X with Nix instead of Homebrew?

Tags: ruby, nix

I switched recently to the Nix package manager instead of Homebrew for OS X.

Usually, I install it with rbenv like:

```
brew install rbenv
rbenv install 2.2.0
```

I am asking myself now how does one do it with Nix? I've heard Nix itself is a good enough package manager, so maybe I can get rid of `rbenv` for handling my ruby version?

When I install ruby via Nix

```
nix-env -i ruby
```

Even when OS X recognises it:

```
$ which ruby
/Users/USERNAME/.nix-profile/bin/ruby
```

I am still getting a `Permission denied` error when trying to:

```
gem install sass
```

> Would you still recommend rbenv for handling ruby installations? I
>   know I could just chown the Nix folder, but I should own it anyway.

Comment: "To list all available packages:

`$ nix-env -qa`". Did you do that? Is there a package for ruby in nix?

Comment: Yes there is, but I am still not able to run gem install without sudo. So do I have to install rbenv through other sources still?

Comment: You may want to look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32847962/ensure-ruby-version-in-nix-dev-environment-when-using-latest-version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had similar experience using python with `nix`. 
Generally the approach when using nix is **NOT** to:

- Install a language specific package manager for some version of a language (`gem`, `pip`, ...)
- Use that language specific package manager to install libraries

Instead the `nix` way (from what I've learned) to do things is:

- Install all already packaged applications with `nix`
- If you are developing an application, instead of installing the libraries your application depends on via `nix` (or `gem`), you define a `nix` expression that describes your applications dependencies and use it as a *development environment*. (I think the documentation should be improved in this matter.)
- Generally don't install libraries on their own and manually refer to those in some third-party build process. (This works in some scenarios, as in compiled C/C++ libraries, where dependencies of the libraries are built into them via `RPATH`s. But this does not work well with e.g. python packages.) In the end what you really want is the application, not the library!

You can find some documentation on how to set up such environments in the official [`nixpkgs` documentation](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#how-to-create-a-development-environment), mostly covering Haskell at the moment, but Ruby should be similar.

Answer (score 1):

you can found package of ruby by following

```
nix-env -qa ruby
```

and then it will shows list of ruby versions

```
nix-env -i ruby-2.1.0-p0
```

This will install ruby version then check it by `ruby -v`

Comment: When I do ruby -v, I still have the old one, and not the one which Nix installed. How can I point to the Nix ruby?

Comment: So for that you can go with rvm, which helps you to switching between rubies easily